# 'httprequestbegin' pipeline in live web page

Tags: configuration, experience-editor, pipelines

i want to process certain operation at 'httprequestbegin' pipeline in live web page (CM or CD) i.e.

- notequals to PageEditor,
- notequals to ExperienceEditor,
- notequals to ContentEditor,
- notequals to Preview

After some analysis & references from this link 
[Most reliable way to detect if running in live site?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/2807/most-reliable-way-to-detect-if-running-in-live-site)

My code snippet looks like

```
if (Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsNormal 
&& !Sitecore.Context.Site.Name.ToLower.Equals("shell"))
{
//Do task here
}
```

**Question:**
since we have default websites like shell,login,services,scheduer,system etc, do i need to include all the sites in the above
condition to get out of default websites provided by sitecore. I have noticed 'service' website is triggering a request which would bypass the above condition.

Any inputs on this please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we are using multi-tenant solution, I'm able to achieve this by below code. i.e. verifying domain equals to "extranet" & hostname not equals to null/empty.

```
 if (Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsNormal 
          && GetSites().Where(x =>x.Name.ToLower()
            .Equals(Sitecore.Context.Site.Name.ToLower()))
{
         //Do task here
}



 private List<SiteInfo> GetSites()
    {
        List<SiteInfo> sitesInformation = Factory.GetSiteInfoList();
        if (sitesInformation != null && sitesInformation.Count > 0)
        {
            return sitesInformation.Where(s => s.Domain != null 
                     && s.Domain == "extranet" 
                     && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.HostName)).ToList();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You may add the following settings in a configuration file:

```
<settings>
    <!-- Sites to ignore by custom processors -->
    <setting name="SitesToIgnoreByCustomProcessors" value="shell,login,admin,service,scheduler,system,publisher,modules_shell,modules_website"/>
    <setting name="LinksToIgnoreByCustomProcessors" value="-/media/,~/media/,/layouts/system/visitoridentification,/api/sitecore,-/speak,-/item,/sitecore"/>
</settings>
```

All the sites and links that you do not want to process can be included in the above settings. The you perform a check as follows:

```
    var settings = Settings.GetSetting("SitesToIgnoreByCustomProcessors", string.Empty)
            .ToLowerInvariant()
            .Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .ToList<string>();

//Request to perform when site is not Equal to sitecore default sites. (EDITED)
    if (Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsNormal && !settings.Contains(Context.Site.Name.ToLowerInvariant()))
    {
        //Do task here
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

All the internal sites have domain property set to `sitecore` so you could check the domain property of the context site:

```
if (Sitecore.Context.Site.Domain != Sitecore.Security.Domains.Domain.GetDomain("sitecore"))
{
    // [Do stuff here]
}
```

You can find [more details on this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21202662/661447) from @Trayek. Also note the extension method in the other answer from @MartinDavies

Comment: but modules_website's domain name is 'extranet'. how would that be ignored ? correct me if iam wrong.